# Converting .class file to .cap JavaCard 3.0.2 Connected Edition

Tags: java, compilation, javacard

I want to make use of the new api function such as strings, threads, longs etc...I'm struggling to convert the class file to cap file when I include Strings in my code, the converter gives me errors: "unsupported String type constant". When I remove the String, then the converter converts it to a cap file without errors.  Is there something extra I need to do to convert .class to .cap to use the connected api?

Using: JavaCard302 and jdk1.6u11

wrote a bat file that does my compiling and converting:

```
echo off

set appName=testCrypt


set targetdir=C:\SC\%appName%\%appName%
rmdir /S /Q %targetdir%


..\JDK1.6\bin\javac.exe -g -d %appName% -classpath ".;%JC_HOME%\lib\api_connected.jar" %appName%.java

..\JavaCard302\bin\converter.bat -i -applet 0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00:0x00 %appName%.%appName% -classdir %appName% -exportpath %JC_HOME%\api_export_files %appName% 0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00 1.0
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, Is there any Java Card Connected Edition compatible real smart card available now? or you want to try it with simulator or something?

Answer (score 1):

CAP files are only for classic applets. Connected applets are servlets packaged in JAR files.

JavaCard classic edition supports a very limited subset of Java. In particular Strings are not supported. This is why the CAP converter is rejecting your code.

To my knowledge, the connected edition is a dead technology. No smart-card product supports it.

The reason is that It was developed to support big SIM cards with lots of memory and high bandwidth interfaces (USB, MMC) but these never took up. Today's SIM cards or Secure Elements are still very limited devices.

Answer (score 0):

Javacard only support below keywords，It is only a subset of Java。
abstract  default    if             private          this
boolean   do         implements     protected        throw
break     else       import         public           throws
byte      extends    instanceof     return           try
case      final      int            short            void
catch     finally    interface      static           while
class     for        new            super            switch
continue  goto       package

Comment: 1. Do not support floating-point
2. Do not support the string
3. Do not support the type char
4. A reference type (class, interface, array) storage way is different, exist in the Java memory, shutdown, after power off, has not had, but, of the block is stored in the EEPROM in the javacard after power off, still exist.
5. The garbage collection in JAVA is automatic recovery, have to call in the javacard JCSystem. RequestObjectDeletion () to recycle, the function is just request garbage collection, not immediately, but can guarantee in the next article apdu has been ahead of garbage collection